# Dynamic IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Is there a way to get the type dynamically that can be assigned to an `IEnumerable<T>`?

I have a country class with few properties and a `List<string>` class that holds some values.
The below code that I have written is checking specifically for country class with else as string.

```cs
var countryInfo = parentList as IEnumerable<Countries>;

var selectItems = countryInfo == null
    ? ((IEnumerable<string>)parentList).Select(item => new SelectItem() { Value = item, Text = item.ToString() })
    : countries.Select(country => new SelectItem() { Value = country.Name, Text = country.Name });
```

I am looking out for a solution that would dynamically get the type which I can bind to `IEnumerable<>` which will let me avoid the ternary check.

Comment: Why in the world would you want to do that, rather than having the sequence always reliably be of the same type?

Comment: What is the type of `parentList`. I mean the type you declared the variable/parameter `parentList` as, not the type of whichever object happens to be in there.

Comment: Do you mean `(parentList is IEnumerable<Countries> c ? c.Select(c => c.Name) : countries.Select(c => c.Name)).Select(c => new SelectListItem { Value = c, Text = c })`...? Show the relevant types and explain what you want to do, and you'll probably not need dynamic.

Comment: Your example  gives you `IEnumerable<SelectItem>`, which isn't seems to be dynamic type. To make it dynamic type (`'a` or `dynamic`)  with `Value` and `Text` properties - just use `Select(x => new { Value = "", Text = ""})` and at result you'll have an `IEnumerable<'a>` or `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, depending on how you declare it.

Comment: As I can suggest, your `parentList` is `List<string>` ("that holds some values") and your `countries` is `List<Countries>`. This leads us to the fact that calling `parentList as IEnumerable<Countries>` will always give you `null`. So finally, the main question is (thanks to @Servy) **"Why in the world would you want to do that?"**

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using a switch expression:

```
var selectItems = parentList switch{
    IEnumerable<Countries> c => c.Select(item => new SelectItem() { Value = item, Text = item.ToString() }),
    IEnumerable<string> s => s.Select(country => new SelectItem() { Value = country.Name, Text = country.Name }),
_ => throw new Exception(...)
}
```

This would be at least a little bit easier to read than the tertiary expression.

A better solution would be to not get in the situation in the first place. The main problem here is that `parentList` can be multiple different types, while presumably representing the same conceptual thing. This should be avoided by either converting to one specific type when required, or to hide the differences between the types behind an interface. I would probably prefer the former in most cases.